# What are the cheap CDN for Origin Pull?

Tags: cdn

I've read several thread around ServerFault about this, but still I am not satisfy with the answer so I post a question here.

I need a Origin Pull CDN that support big file (more than 200MB). I don't need a storage place since they are too small, just to relay the server.

Also the price should be afforable, ofcourse not more than 150$ a month for their smallest plan.

I also need to pay by credit card since I do not work or stays in the US so it's hard for me to do a bank wire.

Thank you very much

Comment: What good is a CDN if they don't cache any of your data?

Comment: not only cache but also for content providing to different location. I need it for relay. if any service that can relay data for cheap, i can go for it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried cloudfront or maxcdn

they will always cache your data for a preset period of time but you can manually purge the cache or set relevant expires to your content to keep it cached for lower periods of time

without caching the data at edge locations there is absolutely no benefit in using cdn because it actually doubles the connection overhead for a user if a cdn has to get the file from your server everytime also.

Comment: i tried maxcdn, @maxcdn they allow 10MB file only. Do you have any other than CloudFront?

Comment: if you go via vps.net - http://vps.net/product/cdn/?r=lUOA then they have a first 1tb special with level3, after that its not so cheap then, i'm not actually sure you can get origin pull providers for files > 100mb anyway, at least not cheap ones

Answer (score 1):

**You will not get a good CDN to cache your >200 MB files at high request volume for <150 USD/month.**

In this use case CDNs add most value by *providing massive scalability*, i.e. many downloads per second. For very large files, the speed gain by placing the content closer to the end user is a lot less important compared to small files -- when properly set up, TCP/IP can auto-tune itself on large downloads.

**Some suggestions:**

- Amazon Cloudfront. Dirt cheap at lower data transfer volumes (but not at high volume), easy to set up, clear business model. Downside: Latency (time to first byte) is in my experience very high, often in the 300-500 msec range.
- MaxCDN or NetDNLA (their parent company) or their streaming media CDN. Cheap, friendly service, check with their support whether they can accomodate your requirements.

**But you should probably look at:**

- [FileBurst](http://www.fileburst.com/). Large capacity downloads provider.
- [Download Tech](http://downloadtech.com/), also a large scale file hosting provider.
- Just plain Amazon S3, without Cloudfront. Still massively scalable.
- A bunch of servers (VPS, dedicated, whatever) with good bandwidth allowances, and simple DNS Round Robin to use the same URL for all the servers.

Comment: A bunch of servers with simple DNS round robin is simply the best choice